# Get category name in php feed Magento with main and subcategories

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

We have a producfeed for Magento that is made in php and is making an .xml productfeed. In the image below you can see how we run the loop to get the products in the xml feed. We are also getting the categories with the following code:

```
//Prepare the loop 
        foreach($prodIds as $productId) { 
            $product->load($productId); 
            $product_data = array();     
    //Get product data 
        $product_data['title']=$product->getName(); 
        $product_data['description']= strip_tags($product->getDescription()); 
        $product_data['sku']=$product->getSku(); 
        $product_data['color']=$product->getResource()->getAttribute('color')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
        if($product->getSpecialPrice())
            $product_data['price']=number_format($product->getSpecialPrice(), 2);
        else
            $product_data['price']=number_format($product->getPrice(), 2);
        $product_data['specialprice']=number_format($product->getSpecialPrice(), 2);
        $product_data['old_price']=number_format($product->getPrice(), 2);
        $product_data['availability']="Op voorraad";
        $product_data['shippingcost']="6.95"; 
        $product_data['delivery_time']="2 tot 5 werkdagen"; 
        $product_data['link']=Mage::getBaseUrl().$product->getUrlPath(); 
        $product_data['image_link']=Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'catalog/product'.$product->getImage();
        $product_data['image_link_small']= Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(200,200);



    //Get feed category data 

        $childIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getChildrenIds($product->getId());
    // Echo run the loop 
    ?> 
        <product> 
            <sku><![CDATA[<?php echo $product_data['sku'] ?>]]></sku> 
            <link><![CDATA[<?php echo $product_data['link'].$source ?>]]></link> 
            <title><![CDATA[<?php echo $product_data['title'] ?>]]></title> 
            <description><![CDATA[<?php echo $product_data['description'] ?>]]></description> 
            <image_link><![CDATA[<?php echo $product_data['image_link'] ?>]]></image_link> 
            <image_link_small><![CDATA[<?php echo $product_data['image_link_small'] ?>]]></image_link_small>  
            <price><![CDATA[<?php echo $product_data['price'] ?>]]></price>
            <old_price><![CDATA[<?php echo $product_data['old_price'] ?>]]></old_price>
            <availability><![CDATA[<?php echo $product_data['availability'] ?>]]></availability>
            <delivery_time><![CDATA[<?php echo $product_data['delivery_time'] ?>]]></delivery_time>
            <id><![CDATA[<?php echo $product_data['sku'] ?>]]></id> 
            <delivery_costs><![CDATA[<?php echo $product_data['shippingcost'] ?>]]></delivery_costs> 
            <special_price><![CDATA[<?php echo $product_data['specialprice'] ?>]]></special_price>

             <categories><?php $categoryCollection = $product->getCategoryCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('name');?><?php foreach($categoryCollection as $cat): ?><subcat><?php echo htmlentities($cat->getName()); ?></subcat><?php endforeach; ?></categories>



        </product> 

        <?php } //End of loop ?> 
        </products>
```

Now we want to make a difference between the main categories and the subcategories. With the code above we get a list with all categories and it should be two fields, one with main categories and one with subcategories.

Can someone help me modify the code?

Answer (score 2):

You can check if a category is top category by it's level.

```
if ($category->getLevel() == 2){
   //is top category
}
elseif ($category->getLevel() > 2){
   //is subcategory
}
```

and next time post the code, not the screenshot. What is this, a question for ants? :)

Comment: Marius, thanks for your reply and comment on the screenshot, I just replaced it with a part of the code we are using. In the part <categories>...</categories> we are showing the categories. Now we need to keep that one only for the categories and a new line for the subcategories. Hope you can help

Comment: Dear Marius, did you have time to have a look at my question? Thanks

Comment: @Coen I did. And I offered a solution on how to check if the category is top level or not. It's up to you how you integrate that in your code.